# How require work under the hood in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, require

I try to understand how bootstrapping of nodeJS works, but I am stacked with the function `require`

1. First use of require inside `internal/bootstrap/node.js` (See picture below)
2. require passed to this file in `src/node.cc` as `native_module_require`
3. node.cc take require from `internal/bootstrap/loaders.js` (which executed before step 1)
4. `internal/bootstrap/loaders.js` use `internalBinding`, which use `getInternalBinding`
5. `getInternalBinding` create from ...
6. `src/node_binding.cc`, looks a little bit complicated, but my case (`"native_module"` from step 4) is `findModule(modlist_internal...`
7. `modlist_internal` saved in `node_module_register`
8. which is called from `napi_module_register`
9. which is called from `NAPI_MODULE`
10. but I cannot find where `NAPI_MODULE` is used (except for test and bench)

[image: code blocks]

I use 16.14.0 LTS version of nodeJS from GitHub

What I am trying to do? Nothing special, just curiosity, I also study the source code of the old project, which can run node inside the browser  https://github.com/olydis/node-in-browser, but it use old version of nodeJS (with different `require`), and the project is not updated few years. Also, I am wondering, how stackblitz.com launch a modern version of nodeJS inside the browser.

P.S. there is also folder lib\internal\modules\ which is somehow related to `require` and `import` but I don't think its used in bootstrapping process, maybe a little bit later

P.P.S. I know only javaScript, so I can miss something important in C++ source code

Comment: I don't think that `internal/bootstrap/node.js` actually uses `require`. It just exports its own function named `nativeModuleRequire` with the name `require`. This is something different from `native_module_require`. I stopped at point 2. but the rest of your analysis doesn't look quite correct either. Have you tried to run your own build of Node.js in a debugger?

Comment: so there is a comment inside internal/bootstrap/node.js

 `//This file is invoked by node::RunBootstrapping() in src/node.cc`


inside node.cc native_module_require(), is passed to internal/bootstrap/node.js
and in step 3 u see that native_module_require is loaded from loaders.js

Answer (score 0):

In the .data section of the node executable there are C++ strings that contain native js sources.  In the .text section of the node executable are executable code fragments compiled from those strings.  V8 maintains the bindings between the native js sources and the executable code fragments through mappings inside the global object of the V8 instance's isolate, and node sets up the V8 isolate with the correct mappings/bindings during initialization.  Require is one of the native js sources.

Further js code is converted into executable code and data by node through V8.  Your program, which calls require, is such js code.  Since require is a native js module, a binding to executable code exists, so V8 knows which address to use when compiling the call.  The implementation of require has logic to find out whether its argument is a native module or not, as there's different logic for importing native vs non-native modules.

So a call to require works by getting compiled to a call to a pre-compiled function that is part of the node executable that V8 knows about thanks to node's set up of V8.